# Swift Add float value to UISlider.value

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Khai bao bien
    var time:Float = 0
    var timer:NSTimer!
    var sliTime:Float!

    // End khai bao
    @IBOutlet weak var sldTime: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblScore: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNum1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOperator: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNum2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
    @IBAction func btnOK(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    @IBAction func btnCan(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sldTime.minimumValue = 0
        sldTime.maximumValue = 10
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Run") ,userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func Run()
    {
        if time == 0{
            time = 10
        }else{
            time = time - 1
            sldTime.value = time
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When I run app in simulator , the app show:

> "Thread 1 breakpoint 1.1" in line sldTime.value = time

Comment: Delete the breakpoint you added and/or click on the "continue" button in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

What does the debugger console say? Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error if that's what the console says that mean you made a bad connection from the Main Story board to the ViewController Go to the Outlet Connection > and delete a connection you made but it's no longer in use. And try to run it again. Just keep in mind that Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Error is due to a connection problem between the Storyboard and ViewController mostly.

```
time = sldTime.floatValue
```

Comment: sorry . sldTime don't have floatValue ... sldTime.value required Float